# Get the real name of saved file (Model) after upload - Django

Tags: django, model, upload

I'm trying to get the real name of the uploaded file in Django. It turns out that if a file name already exists inside the Model, the Django will create another name aleatory.

For example, if 'abc.xls' is inside the Model database and I try to upload 'abc.xls' again, Django will create a file called 'abc_123456.xls'. That's not the problem!

My question is: how can I get this name ('abc_123456.xls') inside my `view.py`?

```
def index(request):
    if 'GET' == request.method:
        form = DocumentForm()
        return render(request, 'auditoria_app/index.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            
            # I'd like to get the correct file name here!

            mediaFolder = settings.MEDIA_ROOT

            fileName = f"{mediaFolder}/SAE/{form.cleaned_data['file'].get_alternative_name}" # .xlsm (Excel file)
            splitFileName = fileName.split('.')
            zipFileName = f"{splitFileName[0]}.zip" # .zip
```

My model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator

class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='SAE/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve it from file with `name` attribute. Bu it gives you file name with joined MEDIA_ROOT. You can extract MEDIA_ROOT from that attribute. Also you can retrieve object when `form.save(commit=False)` Try this:

```
def index(request):
    if 'GET' == request.method:
        form = DocumentForm()
        return render(request, 'auditoria_app/index.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.save()

            # you can get file_name like this
            file_name = document.file.name.split('/')[-1]
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get! How am I suppose to get 'document', by making a query? If so, mustn't I provide an id to search for the correct record? I mean, if I need to do that, I may end up in the same question: how can I get the uploaded file name?

Comment: Ok, I updated answer, can you review again